# Using @Value to retrieve application classpath in Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to get the classpath of the web application deployed on tomcat so that I know where to store my xml file.

```
class MyClass { 

    @Value("${classpath:}")
    private String classpath;

}
```

It doesn't work.

How can I get the classpath?

I need to get something like this: "C:/Tomcat/webapp/WEB-INF/classes".

Comment: Don't store files other than those required to run the application in the directories used for your application's classpath.

Comment: I need it right there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the system properties

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['java.class.path']}")
private String classPath;
```

Note that this will give you a comma separated list of all the directories and `jar` URIs used in the classpath.

---

Tomcat is not required to unzip your `war`, so your web app may be running from inside its archive. As such, a path like

```
C:/Tomcat/webapp/your-app/WEB-INF/classes
```

may not exist.

For files your application is generating, decide for yourself a dedicated directory and put them there.